# Rearrange array

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting this array when form is submitted

```
array
  'item' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Salt'
      1 => string 'Pepper'
  'quantity' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '2 spoon'
      1 => string '5'
```

and now want to rearrange above array, so it should look like

```
array
  '0' => 
    array
      'item' => string 'Salt'
      'quantity' => string '2 spoon'
  '1' => 
    array
      'item' => string 'Pepper'
      'quantity' => string '5'
```

I tried so many combinations but failed, will somebody help me how to rearrange this array. Any help will be more than appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you have tried in the question.

Comment: what form? please provide more details in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$array = array(
    'item' =>
    array(
        0 => 'Salt',
        1 => 'Pepper'),
    'quantity' =>
    array(
        0 => '2 spoon',
        1 => '5')
);
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array['item'] as $key => $value) {
    $new_array[$key]["item"] = $value;
    $new_array[$key]["quantity"] = $array['quantity'][$key];
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($new_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

try this, I think this would help you,

```
$a = array(
        'item' =>
        array(
            0 => 'Salt',
            1 => 'Pepper'),
        'quantity' =>
        array(
            0 => '2 spoon',
            1 => '5')
    );

    $i = 0;
    foreach($a['item'] as $row){
        $b[$i]["item"] = $row;
        $b[$i]["quantity"] = $a['quantity'][$i];
        $i++;
    }
    print_r($b);
```

Output from `print_r()` will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => Salt
            [quantity] => 2 spoon
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => Pepper
            [quantity] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: Why are you using a counter?

Comment: @AgeDeO why not? The elements which need to be joined share the same index in different arrays :P

Comment: You could use the key of the array btw ;)

Comment: @nowhere It's an extra variable and when the keys do have a meaning in the array (you don't know they don't) the code is going to break

Answer (score 3):

Do it as below -

```
<?php
$arr=array(
  'item' => 
    array(
      0 => 'Salt' ,
      1 => 'Pepper'
       ),
  'quantity' => 
    array (
      0 =>'spoon',
      1 =>'5'
      )
);
$result=array();
$com=array_combine($arr['item'],$arr['quantity']);
foreach($com as $k=>$v)
{
   $result[]=array("item"=>$k,"quantity"=>$v);
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 Array ( 
          [0] => Array ( [item] => Salt [quantity] => spoon )
          [1] => Array ( [item] => Pepper [quantity] => 5 ) 
          )
```

Comment: Instead of using function and foreach simply use `foreach`

Comment: yep @Uchiha ,it just came fast to me so this ..i hadn't deleted since just showing an alternative :)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `array_walk` like as

```
$result = [];
array_walk($arr['item'], function($v, $k)use(&$result, $arr) {
   $result[$k]['item'] = $arr['item'][$k];
   $result[$k]['quantity'] = $arr['quantity'][$k];
});
print_r($result);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/447478)

Comment: Still outputs first two elements if array has more than 2 elements, check https://eval.in/447453

Comment: Updated as per your requirement @Adnan

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that your array is stored in the `$array` variable and that `item` is leading. Meaning that there is always an item in the array and not always a quantity

```
<?php
foreach($array['item'] as $key => $item) {
   $newArray[$key]['item'] = $item;
   if (isset($array['quantity'][$key]) {
      $newArray[$key]['quantity'] = $array['quantity'][$key];
   } else {
      $newArray[$key]['quantity'] = 0;
}
?>
```